# Using trim in php I'd like to use two conditions or an array of conditions to trim?

Tags: php, arrays

This is the idea I'm trying to achieve

```
$foo = $data['string']; 
$bar = trim(preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $data['string']), "_" || "-"); 
echo $bar;
```

The results I'm trying to achieve:

example_ to example

or

example- to example

My scenario using **preg_replace()** in some cases may end with "_" or "-". In which case I wanna use **trim()** to remove it. Obviously the case is to keep those characters within the string:

Example_example_ to Example_example

or

Example-example- to Example-example

Comment: Basically you want to remove every – and _ if it is at the end of a word?

Comment: [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) lets you set a second parameter with characters you want stripped

Comment: Yes that is the case @Zuyas. That is what I'm trying to learn what to do. I've tried different ways to achieve that.

Comment: Are you trying to create seo URL ?

Comment: Yes @Dilek. I already have it completed with my **preg_replace()** array. I have special regex replacements set to achieve the output I wanted to get. This was my final step in the process.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `"_" || "-"` is `TRUE`, because the PHP logical operators always return a boolean value, and both of these strings are truthy. The second argument to `trim()` is required to be a string, and `TRUE` converts to the string `"1"`, so you're trimming that character from the strings.

The second argument to `trim()` should just be a string containing all the characters you want to remove from the end, not an expression with `||`.

```
$bar = trim(preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $data['string']), "_-");
```

Comment: This worked. I didn't expect a second parameter to be that straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Give the characters you want to trim as the second parameter to `trim()`:

```
$string = 'Example_example_';

echo trim($string, '_-'); //Example_example
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex:

> (-|_)(?:^|\s)

```
$re = '/(-|_)(?:^|\s)/m';
$str = 'The is test-test_ and Test_test- and the end';

$str = preg_replace($re,'',$str);

echo $str;
```

would output:

> The is test-testand Test_testand the end

Comment: This didn't work in my scenario as the data/string will not have any spaces in between words or numbers. And this also did not take away the intended from the **EOL** as I was trying to accomplish when set into my 'preg_replace()' array.